# Подсчет количества квадратных уравнений с заданными корнями

Tags: алгоритм

Задача заключается в том, чтобы посчитать количество возможных квадратных уравнений при заданных корнях.

В программу поступает список длина списка и список с возможными корнями, к примеру [1,1,2,3]
Нужно посчитать количество различных квадратных уровненный которые можно составить с парами из этого списка. В этом случае пары будут выглядеть так [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]. Если хотя бы один коэффициент различается уравнения считаются разными. В этом примере максимальное количество 4.

Максимальная длина входящего списка 2*10^5. А числа содержащиеся в списке по модулю не превышают 10^9. Время ограничено в 1 секунду. Память в 256 мегабайт.

Очевидно, что для решения этой задачи не нужно в лоб строить все возможные уравнения. Достаточно посчитать количество не повторяющихся пар.

Моё решение:

```
import itertools
N=int(input())
tmp=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
lst=sorted(set(list(itertools.combinations(tmp, 2))))
print(len(lst))
```

Вроде бы компактно и просто, но по времени и памяти укладывается далеко не всегда.

Результат тестировщика:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWWWWAAAAAWWWWWAAATWWTTTMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM

 A = ACCEPTED = решение засчитано как верное
 W = Wrong Answer = неверный ответ на тесте
 T = Time limit exceeded = решение не уложилось в отведенное процессорное время
 M = Memory limit exceeded = решение не уложилось в отведенное ограничение по памяти
```

Подскажите как можно более оптимально решить задачу.

p.s. Вариант Harry, дал следующий результат:

```
N=int(input())
tmp=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
N = len(sorted(set(tmp)))
M = (sum(tmp.count(x) - 1 for x in tmp) // 2)
print(int(N*(N-1)/2+M))

AAWAAAAAAAAAWAWWWWWAAWAWWWWWWAWWWAWWWAAWWWAWWWAAWTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

Comment: А корни 2, 2 в вашем примере допустимы? Формально это один двойной корень...

Comment: В списке из примера поступает только одна 2, поэтому не может получится два корня 2,2. С двойкой будут взаимодействовать только остальные элементы. 2,1 и 2,3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, *если я верно понял* вашу задачу - из множества вам надо выбрать все различные пары.

Сортируем (самая длинная операция, но сортировка 200000 элементов - дело очень быстрое...), и, линейно проходя, смотрим

1. сколько есть разных значений корней - N
2. сколько есть корней, которых одинаковых хотя бы 2 - M

В вашем случае N=3, M=1.

Все, искомое число - N*(N-1)/2+M (в вашем случае 3*2/2+1 = 4).

Думаю, напишете сами? Потому как я в Python не сведущ... Но уверен - встроенная быстрая сортировка в Python есть :) Если же корни поступают так, как у вас - отсортированными - то вообще проблем нет.

P.S. Если это общедоступный ресурс - дайте URL поиграться...

P.P.S. Попробуйте этот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int N;
    cin >> N;
    if (N < 2) { cout << "0\n"; return 0; }
    map<int,int> v;
    for(int i = 0, j; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cin >> j;
        v[j]++;
    }
    N = v.size();
    long long int M = 0;
    for(auto p: v) if (p.second > 1) ++M;

    cout << (M+N*(N-1)/2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ресурс к сожалению закрытый. Попробовал ваш вариант (результат добавил в сабж).

Comment: Там есть возможность на С++ ввести? Просто уже интересно :)

Comment: да, кстати вот полное условие https://i.ibb.co/pxx9VvY/image.png

Comment: Попробуйте код на С++, который я в ответ добавил.

Answer (score 1):

У вас на несортированных входных данных неверный результат, вы сортируете не в том месте и не то. Так же нет необходимости конвертировать входные данные в целые числа, а результаты в список, это ничего не дает (кроме того, не используется N, но тут уже в условиях не сказано, что делать, если на входе данных меньше или больше, чем N).

Проверьте такое:

```
import itertools
N = int(input())
tmp = input().split()
tmp = sorted(tmp)
res = set(itertools.combinations(tmp, 2))
print (len(res))
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Но по времени и памяти, не укладывается. Видимо, алгоритмы itertools слишком трудоемки. Надо будет попробовать на си

Comment: Попробуйте новый вариант, я убрал цикл на вводе (строка 3), он тоже не нужен.

Comment: это не влияет на трудоемкость алгоритма

Comment: Зато влияет на время выполнения (проверяется именно оно, а не трудоемкость).

Comment: Вот результат первого: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTMTTTMMTTTMTTTTTTTTMTTTTTTTTMTTTTTTTTMTTTTTT. Вот второго: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTMTTTMMTTTMTTTTTTTTMTTTTTTTTMTTTTTTTTMTTTTTT.

Comment: Ок. А М это что?

Comment: A = ACCEPTED = решение засчитано как верное
W = Wrong Answer = неверный ответ на тесте
T = Time limit exceeded = решение не уложилось в отведенное процессорное время

Comment: Это  уже написано в вопросе :) Про М тут ничего нет.

Comment: M = Memory limit exceeded = решение не уложилось в отведенное ограничение по памяти